# There are multiple heroes that share the same tag within a subtree

Tags: flutter

I am trying to navigate from one screen to another with route. When I hit the button for the page to move to the route provided I get the error

```
I/flutter ( 8790): Another exception was thrown: There are multiple heroes that share the same tag within a subtree.
```

Here's the code:

Routes:

```
 <String, WidgetBuilder>{
    '/first':(BuildContext context) =>NavigatorOne() ,
    '/second':(BuildContext context) =>NavigatorTwo(),
    '/third':(BuildContext context) =>NavigatorThree(),

  },

Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/first');
Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/second');
Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/third');

class NavigatorOne extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NavigatorOneState createState() =>  _NavigatorOneState();
}

class _NavigatorOneState extends State<NavigatorOne> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(

      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Container(
      color: Colors.green,
      child: RaisedButton(child: Text(' one 1'),onPressed: (){
        Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/second');
      },),
    ),
    ); 
  }
}
```

And The Error:

`══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY SCHEDULER LIBRARY ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (21786): The following assertion was thrown during a scheduler callback:
I/flutter (21786): There are multiple heroes that share the same tag within a subtree.
I/flutter (21786): Within each subtree for which heroes are to be animated (typically a PageRoute subtree), each Hero
I/flutter (21786): must have a unique non-null tag.
I/flutter (21786): In this case, multiple heroes had the following tag: <default FloatingActionButton tag>`

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 731, accepted):

I have encountered this before, and it was because I had two `FloatingAction` buttons on one screen, I had to add a heroTag property + value per `FloatingActionButton` in order for the error to go away.

Example:

```dart
FloatingActionButton(
    heroTag: "btn1",
    ...
)

FloatingActionButton(
    heroTag: "btn2",
    ...
)
```

From the example code you provided it doesn't appear that you have a `FloatingActionButton`, but from the error it does seem to reference it:

```
I/flutter (21786): In this case, multiple heroes had the following tag: default FloatingActionButton tag
```

Perhaps you used it on the page you were navigating to which then triggered the error. Note that if you're using a programmatic way of creating tagged heroes, you will need to find a way of giving them different tags. For example, if you have a `ListView.builder()` creating `FloatingActionButtons`, try passing tags with string formatting so each button has a different tag, e.g.: `heroTag: "btn$index"`.

Comment: You can simply nullify it: heroTag: null,

Comment: Similar issues would be in a `ListTile` with a `Hero` inside. this `Hero` is not just one hero, but it is multiplied by your `items.length`, so the tag should be `'tag$index'`

Comment: how can I add a hero inside a GridView?

Comment: Wow!  I was navigating to a black screen.  Knew the screen was loading properly as I put an auto-play sound file on it to test.  Finally noticed this "hero" error message and found your response - thank you!  Very helpful indeed.

Comment: Thank you. I have multiple FloatingActionButtons and this solution worked for me.

Comment: I am not using any heroTag in my entire app but still getting error at the compile time "There are multiple heroes that share the same tag within a subtree" kindly suggest what is the issue and how can I solve it. Thanks.

Comment: @Robert Robert, could you please see my last message and suggest me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Don't want to start a new questions, my issue if someone could answer: `In this case, multiple heroes had the following tag: <SnackBar Hero tag - Column(direction:
vertical, mainAxisAlignment: start, mainAxisSize: min, crossAxisAlignment: stretch)>`

Comment: I had a similar issue while navigating between two pages with their own FAB. Setting heroTag to null solved the error.

Comment: But why in the documentation it says the tags should be the same?!!!!

Comment: @mik, I think it sets a default tag when you null it. But I do not know how it was in  2019. :)

Answer (score 91):

You can set a unique id or only set `null`:

```
FloatingActionButton(
  heroTag: null,
  ...
)
```

Comment: I have no `FloatingActionButton` in my entire project but still getting this error when I navigate from child to parent screen. Please suggest me what is the solution? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Kamlesh The remaining exception would indicate the widget that need the `heroTag`. "In this case, multiple heroes had the following tag: <default FloatingActionButton tag>

Comment: It worked like a charm but is there side effects to this ?

Answer (score 26):

Just for Readers in the future:

in appreciate to @m.vincent comment, what cause this error for me is that i was using Hero inside `SliverChildBuilderDelegate` which (obviously) has an index, so i used the index with the tag like `'tag$index'` like this

```
SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
    (BuildContext context, int index) {
      return Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            Hero(
              tag: 'tagImage$index',
              child: Image.asset(
                'image source here',
              ),
            ),
```

NOTE : this may happen with any widget with index created children like ListView.Builder

Comment: Thanks, it's very helpful. When you navigate to the next page then pass tap index too. To match the tap Hero tag and next page hero tag name.

Comment: This is exactly the solution I wanted, thank you.

Answer (score 13):

Yet another approach:

```
FloatingActionButton(
    heroTag: UniqueKey(),
    ....  
)
```

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/UniqueKey-class.html

`UniqueKey()`
Creates a key that is equal only to itself.

Answer (score 8):

For me, just adding a unique `heroTag` to my `FloatingActionButtons` didn't work.  I ended up wrapping the `heroTag` in a `Text` widget and that solved the problem for me.

```
new FloatingActionButton(
    heroTag: Text("btn1"),
    ...
)

new FloatingActionButton(
    heroTag: Text("btn2"),
    ...
)
```

Comment: This is really bizarre.

Comment: I have no `FloatingActionButton` in my entire project but still getting this error when I navigate from child to parent screen. Please suggest me what is the solution? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Don't do this! the hero widget takes an object in this case it will be calling the toString method of the widget

Answer (score 4):

This is correct because according to flutter documentations, it should be one Floating Action Button per route (Screen) unless you explicit set the hero tag.

[Flutter Docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/FloatingActionButton/heroTag.html)

> if this is not explicitly set, then there can only be one
> FloatingActionButton per route (that is, per screen), since otherwise
> there would be a tag conflict (multiple heroes on one route can't have
> the same tag). The material design specification recommends only using
> one floating action button per screen.

Answer (score 3):

I went through same Error. It is because of use of buttons like floating action button multiple times in single screen.
Previously I used a *floating action button* instead I changed it to a *gesture detector* to use ontap so it worked

```
  GestureDetector(

              //backgroundColor: Colors.amber[100],
              onTap: add,
              child: Icon(
                FontAwesomeIcons.plus,
                size: 30,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: 20,
            ),
            GestureDetector(
             // heroTag: "btn2",
             // backgroundColor: Colors.amber[100],
              onTap: sub,
              child: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.minus, size: 30),
            ),
```

Comment: I also got this error because on one screen I used multiple floating action buttons (4 floating over a video player).

Answer (score 2):

Add as many widgets as you like with hero tags as Strings

```
  Widget floatingButt(Function function, IconData icon, String heroTag) {
    return FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: function,
      heroTag: heroTag,
      materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.padded,
      backgroundColor: Constants.primaryColor, // from your values file
      child: Icon(
        icon,
        size: 36.0,
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: I have no FloatingActionButton in my entire project but still getting this error when I navigate from child to parent screen. Please suggest me what is the solution? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I made the simple mistake of trying to pass a Scaffold into the child of another widget, this threw the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Simply set `tag: Uuid()` if having multiple items with the same tag.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution of this heroTag issue is to provide this property as unique value. Either it can be a String value. In my case i provided it a String casted index value. And following is my solution which is working perfectly

```
FloatingActionButton(
  onPressed: (){ 
    print(index); 
    Navigator.push( context, 
       MaterialPageRoute( builder: (context)=> AddLead()
       ),
     );
    }, 
  heroTag: '$index',
  child: Image.asset('assets/pencil.png',height: 30, width: 30,), backgroundColor: Constants.myColor, 
),
```

for more information follow this link https://wise4rmgodadmob.medium.com/how-to-solve-there-are-multiple-heroes-that-share-the-same-tag-within-a-subtree-a5146fdec2b8

Comment: I am not using any heroTag in my entire app but still getting error at the compile time "There are multiple heroes that share the same tag within a subtree" kindly suggest what is the issue and how can I solve it. Thanks.

Comment: Did you get a change to see my posted comment? Kindly check and suggest. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i used  `Get.offAllNamed("/page")` that produce this error. To solve it I have used `Get.toNamed("/page")`

Answer (score 0):

```
 floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        heroTag: null,
        onPressed: () async {
          final value = await Navigator.push(
              context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const Cargar()));
          if (value == "inserted") {
            setState(() {});
          }
        },
        child: const Icon(Icons.person_add_alt_1),
      ),
```

floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
heroTag: null,
onPressed: () async {
final value = await Navigator.push(
context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const Cargar()));
if (value == "inserted") {
setState(() {});
}
},
child: const Icon(Icons.person_add_alt_1),
),