# How to use same image for every item in list view

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I am loading an image using the `URL` in grid view. If all the `URL`'s are different it works fine but if the `URL` is same for multiple items in the grid view there is an error.

> There are multiple heroes that share the same tag within a subtree

How to resolve this issue. Please help

Comment: you must give unique hero tag to each images

Comment: Does this answer your question? [There are multiple heroes that share the same tag within a subtree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51125024/there-are-multiple-heroes-that-share-the-same-tag-within-a-subtree)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ListView` index as part of your Hero tag 
conde snippet

```
ListView.builder
 (
    itemCount: litems.length,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    return Hero(
                 tag: "tag_name" + index.toString(),
                 child: yourChild();
               );
    }
 )
```