# How to add Hero animations to my ListView in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, user-interface, animation, dart

I have a ListView that has cards as shown below. I am trying to animate the card to open in a bigger size upon being pressed.

I have already achieved this for a single card however I can not understand how to do this for a ListView. Upon adding the Hero tag on the ListView elements, I get the following error:

```
There are multiple heroes that share the same tag within a subtree.
```

This is the [animation](https://vimeo.com/436398621).

This is the code for the animation:

The first Page:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: Hero(
          tag: 'flutterLogo',
          child: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () => Navigator.push(context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AnimatedPage())),
            child: Card(
              elevation: 4.0,
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
              ),
              child: Container(
                height: 180,
                width: 300,
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
            ),
          )),
    );
  }
```

The Second Page:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Hero(
            tag: 'flutterLogo',
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
              child: Card(
                elevation: 4.0,
                color: Colors.red,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
                ),
                child: Container(
                  height: 200,
                  width: 300,
                  child: Center(child: Text('Hello')),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

And this is the code for my ListView:

```
 SliverList(
        delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
          (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return Hero(
              tag: 'flutterLogo',
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0, bottom: 10),
                child: GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.push(context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => PaymentPage()));
                  },
                  child: Card(
                    elevation: 4.0,
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
                    ),
                    child: Container(
                      height: 180,
                      width: 150,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
          childCount: 4,
        ),
      ),
```

And this is what the list looks like:
[image]

I am trying to open the same
second page as shown in the Animation, after clicking on the card in the List.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [There are multiple heroes that share the same tag within a subtree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51125024/there-are-multiple-heroes-that-share-the-same-tag-within-a-subtree)

Comment: I saw this however i cant understand how to implement this in my case @NileshRathod

Comment: Referring to the link by @NileshRathod, You can do something like this, in `SliverList` use `tag: 'flutterLogo$index'` and modify the `SecondPage` to take `tag` as a parameter like `PaymentPage('flutterLogo$index')` and use in this in the `Hero` widget on `SecondPage`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hero Tags should be different, so in your `SliverList` change your tag to this:

```
tag: 'flutterLogo${index}',
```

and pass the tag to your second page, like this(in case its a `StatefulWidget`):

```
class SecondPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String heroTag;
  SecondPage({Key key, this.heroTag}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SecondPageState createState() => _SecondPageState();
}
```

and then instead of using a simple tag in your second page use something like this:

```
tag: widget.heroTag,
```