# There are multiple heroes that share the same tag within a subtree error without hero or FloatingActionButton widgets in code

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm Working on app, and i'm navigating through pages using routes, i'm not using any hero or FloatingActionButtons but i'm getting this hero related error, does anybody has any idea what could be the cause of that?

Here's the navigation call

```
nextTapped()async{
    if(occasionTitleTxtField.text.isEmpty || dateTxtField.text.isEmpty || detailsTxtField.text.isEmpty)
      ErrorOverlay("Invalid Data", false);
    else
      {
        await LoadingOverlay.of(context).during(UserOperations().createFirstOccasion(context, occasionTitleTxtField.text, dateTxtField.text, detailsTxtField.text, repeatEveryYear, timeLimit)).then((value){
          if(value.elementAt(0) == "true")
              Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/firstGift',arguments: FirstGiftPage(value.elementAt(1),occasionTitleTxtField.text));
        });
      }
  }
```

Here's the route_generator

```
class RouteGenerator {
  static Route<dynamic> generateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    // Getting arguments passed in while calling Navigator.pushNamed
    final args = settings.arguments;

    switch (settings.name) {
      case '/':
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => SplashScreen());
      case '/login':
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => LoginPage());
      case '/homepage':
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => HomePage());
      case '/signUp':
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => SignUpScreen());
      case '/otpScreen':
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) {
          OTPScreen screenArgs = args;
          return OTPScreen(screenArgs.phoneNumber,screenArgs.countryCode);
        });
      case '/phoneNumber':
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) {
          PhoneNumberScreen screenArgs = args;
          return PhoneNumberScreen(screenArgs.Provider);
        });
      case '/interests':
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => InterestsPage());
      case '/invitation':
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => InvitationPage());
      case '/firstOccasion':
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => FirstOccasion());
      case '/firstGift':
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) {
          FirstGiftPage screenArgs = args;
          return FirstGiftPage(screenArgs.occasionID,screenArgs.occasionTitle);
        });
      case '/map':
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => MapsPage());
      default:
        return _errorRoute();
    }
  }

  static Route<dynamic> _errorRoute() {
    return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) {
      return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Error'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Text('UnderConstruction'),
        ),
      );
    });
  }
}
```

Page i want to navigate to

```
class FirstGiftPage extends StatefulWidget {
  String occasionID;
  String occasionTitle;
  static LatLng storeLocation;
  FirstGiftPage(this.occasionID,this.occasionTitle);
   @override
  _FirstGiftPageState createState() => _FirstGiftPageState();
}

class _FirstGiftPageState extends State<FirstGiftPage> {
  TextEditingController giftTitleTxtField = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController giftLinkTxtField = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController giftPriceTxtField = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController giftStoreAddTxtField = TextEditingController();
  int giftCounter = 0;
  TextEditingController detailsTxtField = TextEditingController();
  Future<File> imageFile;


  nextTapped()async{
    if(giftTitleTxtField.text.isEmpty || giftLinkTxtField.text.isEmpty || giftPriceTxtField.text.isEmpty || detailsTxtField.text.isEmpty)
      ErrorOverlay("Invalid Data",false);
    else
      {
        Map<String,dynamic> giftData={
          "giftName" : giftTitleTxtField.text,
          "giftLink" : giftLinkTxtField.text,
          "giftPrice" : giftPriceTxtField.text,
          "storeAddress": giftStoreAddTxtField.text,
          "details" : detailsTxtField.text,
          "giftQuantity" : giftCounter,
          "images":[imageFile.toString()],
          "occasionID": widget.occasionID
        };
        ErrorOverlay("Gift Done",true);
        Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed("/homepage");
      }
  }

  showMaps(){
    Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("/map");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
              colors: [
                Color.fromRGBO(246, 76, 77, 1),
                Color.fromRGBO(156, 51, 117, 1)
              ],
              begin: Alignment .topRight,
              end: Alignment.bottomLeft
          )
      ),
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        appBar:AppBar(
          automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          elevation: 0,
          bottom: PreferredSize(
            preferredSize: Size(0.0, 80.0),
            child: Padding(
              //TODO::Change padding to ScreenWidth - 300 / 2
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 55.0 ,right: 55.0,bottom: 30.0),
              child: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context).firstGift,style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: 30.0),textAlign: TextAlign.center,maxLines: 2,),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0,left: 15.0,right: 15.0),
          child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    controller: giftTitleTxtField,
                    obscureText: false,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        filled: true,
                        fillColor: Colors.white,
                        contentPadding:EdgeInsets.only(top:20.0,bottom:20.0,left: 15.0),
                        hintText: AppLocalizations.of(context).giftName,
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              width: 1
                          ),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                        ),
                        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              width: 1
                          ),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                        ),
                        prefix: Container(width: 10.0,),
                        hintStyle: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                          fontSize: 16,
                        )
                    ),),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    controller: giftLinkTxtField,
                    obscureText: false,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        filled: true,
                        fillColor: Colors.white,
                        contentPadding:EdgeInsets.only(top:20.0,bottom:20.0,left: 15.0),
                        hintText: AppLocalizations.of(context).giftLink,
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              width: 1
                          ),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                        ),
                        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              width: 1
                          ),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                        ),
                        prefix: Container(width: 10.0,),
                        hintStyle: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                          fontSize: 16,
                        )
                    ),),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    controller: giftPriceTxtField,
                    obscureText: false,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        filled: true,
                        fillColor: Colors.white,
                        contentPadding:EdgeInsets.only(top:20.0,bottom:20.0,left: 15.0),
                        hintText: AppLocalizations.of(context).giftPrice,
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              width: 1
                          ),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                        ),
                        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              width: 1
                          ),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                        ),
                        prefix: Container(width: 10.0,),
                        hintStyle: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                          fontSize: 16,
                        )
                    ),),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    readOnly: true,
                    onTap: showMaps,
                    controller: giftStoreAddTxtField,
                    obscureText: false,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        filled: true,
                        fillColor: Colors.white,
                        contentPadding:EdgeInsets.only(top:20.0,bottom:20.0,left: 15.0),
                        hintText: AppLocalizations.of(context).giftStoreAdd,
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              width: 1
                          ),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                        ),
                        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              width: 1
                          ),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                        ),
                        hintStyle: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                          fontSize: 16,
                        )
                    ),),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context).giftQuantity,style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Counter(
                          initialValue: giftCounter,
                          minValue: 0,
                          maxValue: 10,
                          step: 1,
                          decimalPlaces: 0,
                          textStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                          onChanged: (value) { // get the latest value from here
                            setState(() {
                              giftCounter = value;
                            });
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    enabled: false,
                    obscureText: false,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        filled: true,
                        fillColor: Colors.white,
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                        hintText: widget.occasionTitle,
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              width: 1
                          ),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                        ),
                        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              width: 1
                          ),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                        ),
                        prefix: Container(width: 10.0,),
                        hintStyle: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                          fontSize: 16,
                        )
                    ),),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    maxLines: null,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
                    controller: detailsTxtField,
                    obscureText: false,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        filled: true,
                        fillColor: Colors.white,
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                        hintText: AppLocalizations.of(context).details,
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              width: 1
                          ),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                        ),
                        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              width: 1
                          ),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                        ),
                        prefix: Container(width: 10.0,),
                        hintStyle: TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                            fontSize: 16,
                            height: 4.0
                        )
                    ),),
                ),
                InkWell(
                  onTap: null,
                  child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Container(
                        width: 50.0,
                        height: 50.0,
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border.all(color: Colors.white,width: 4.0),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(2.0)
                        ),
                        child: Center(
                          child: Icon(Icons.camera_alt_outlined,color: Colors.white,size: 25.0,),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
          child: Container(
            child: Wrap(
              //mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Align(
                    alignment: MyApp.getLocale(context).languageCode == "ar" ? Alignment.centerLeft:Alignment.centerRight,
                    child: Text("(4/5)"),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                    child: LinearProgressIndicator(
                      minHeight: 10.0,
                      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                      value: 0.80,
                      valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.orange),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: InkWell(
                          onTap: (){
                            Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context)=> FirstGiftPage("","")));
                          },
                          child: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context).ignore,style: TextStyle(decoration: TextDecoration.underline),)),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: InkWell(
                        onTap: nextTapped,
                        child: Container(
                          width: 80.0,
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                              gradient: LinearGradient(
                                  colors: [
                                    Color.fromRGBO(246, 76, 77, 1),
                                    Color.fromRGBO(156, 51, 117, 1)
                                  ],
                                  begin: Alignment .topRight,
                                  end: Alignment.bottomLeft
                              )
                          ),
                          child: Center(child: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context).next, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),)),
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here's the error

> ════════ Exception caught by scheduler library ═════════════════════════════════════════════════════
> The following assertion was thrown during a scheduler callback:
> There are multiple heroes that share the same tag within a subtree.

> Within each subtree for which heroes are to be animated (i.e. a PageRoute subtree), each Hero must have a >unique non-null tag.
> In this case, multiple heroes had the following tag:
>
> Here is the subtree for one of the offending heroes: Hero
> tag: 
> state: _HeroState#48fb7
> When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
> #0      Hero._allHeroesFor.inviteHero. >(package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:268:11)
> #1      Hero._allHeroesFor.inviteHero (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:279:8)
> #2      Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:298:21)
> #3      SingleChildRenderObjectElement.visitChildren >(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6105:14)
> #4      Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:311:15)
> ...
> ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

Comment: are you using floating action buttons>

Comment: No, not even one, or any hero animations

Comment: Does this answer your question? [There are multiple heroes that share the same tag within a subtree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51125024/there-are-multiple-heroes-that-share-the-same-tag-within-a-subtree)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by creating a new file for the page i want to navigate to and it worked, have no idea how

Answer (score 2):

If you are using more than one `floating action button` then you need to pass your **own tag** to *each* button like this

```
FloatingActionButton(
    heroTag: "tag1",
)

FloatingActionButton(
    heroTag: "tag2",
)
```

By default, the `heroTag` is `tag` so in this case, you will get an error.

> Second thing

If you are using more than one `hero animation widget` on the **same page** and share the *same tag* then also same **error exist** so you need to pass your **own tag** to each Hero widget

Comment: The problem is i'm not using any Floating Action Buttons or Hero animations and i'm still getting this error, What could go wrong when navigating from one screen to another?

Comment: @FarahMakhlouf kindly please share your code for which page you want to navigate

Comment: I just edited the question with the page's code