# Hero sharing the same tag in your widget tree

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm having a problem with my navigation. I'm using the AutoRoute library. I get the following error (Hero):

```bash
======== Exception caught by scheduler library =====================================================
The following assertion was thrown during a scheduler callback:
There are multiple heroes that share the same tag within a subtree.

Within each subtree for which heroes are to be animated (i.e. a PageRoute subtree), each Hero must have a unique non-null tag.
In this case, multiple heroes had the following tag: <default FloatingActionButton tag>
Here is the subtree for one of the offending heroes: Hero
  tag: <default FloatingActionButton tag>
  state: _HeroState#51baa
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      Hero._allHeroesFor.inviteHero.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:278:11)
#1      Hero._allHeroesFor.inviteHero (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:289:8)
#2      Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:307:11)
#3      SingleChildRenderObjectElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6421:14)
#4      Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:322:15)
#5      ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5138:14)
#6      Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:322:15)
#7      MultiChildRenderObjectElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6533:16)
```

> This error also occurs in my AppBarWidget widget with the back button.

I've tried everything, including wrapping the button with Hero. But nothing works.

Do you have an idea?

My code below.

AppRouter

```dart
@AutoRouterConfig(replaceInRouteName: 'Page,Route')
class AppRouter extends _$AppRouter {

  @override
  List<AutoRoute> get routes => [
    AutoRoute(
        page: DashboardRoute.page,
        path: "/",
        children: [
          AutoRoute(
            page: HomeRoute.page,
            initial: true,
            path: "home",
          ),
          AutoRoute(
            page: HourRoute.page,
            path: "hour",
          ),
          AutoRoute(
            page: ItineraryRoute.page,
            path: "itinerary",
          ),
          AutoRoute(
            page: ProfileRoute.page,
            path: "profile",
          ),
        ],
    ),
    AutoRoute(
      page: AddFavoriteRoute.page,
      path: "/add-favorite",
    ),
    AutoRoute(
      page: FavoritesRoute.page,
      path: "/favorites",
    ),
  ];
}
```

HomePage

```dart
Expanded(
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                      itemCount: favoriteModelView.favoriteStops.length + 1,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        if (index == favoriteModelView.favoriteStops.length) {
                          return Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 3.0),
                            child: Column(
                              children: [
                                ElevatedButton(
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    print('Add Favorites button pressed 1');
                                    context.router.pushNamed("/add-favorite");
                                  },
                                  style: ButtonStyle(
                                    backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.black),
                                    foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.white),
                                    shape: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                                      RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    elevation: MaterialStateProperty.all(0.0),
                                    animationDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
                                  ),
                                  child: const Row(
                                    children: [
                                      Icon(Icons.add, color: Colors.white, size: 20),
                                      SizedBox(width: 10),
                                      Text(
                                        "New",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.white,
                                          fontSize: 16,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          );
                        }

                        final favorite = favoriteModelView.favoriteStops[index];

                        return Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 5.0),
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              ElevatedButton(
                                onPressed: () {
                                  print('Stop button pressed');
                                },
                                style: ButtonStyle(
                                  backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.grey[200]),
                                  shape: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                                    RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  elevation: MaterialStateProperty.all(0.0),
                                ),
                                child: Row(
                                  children: [
                                    Icon(favorite.icon, color: Colors.grey[600], size: 20),
                                    const SizedBox(width: 8),
                                    Text(
                                      favorite.name,
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.grey[600],
                                        fontSize: 16,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  )
```

AppBarWidget

```dart
class AppBarWidget extends HookWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
  final String title;
  final bool showBackButton;

  const AppBarWidget({
    Key? key,
    required this.title,
    this.showBackButton = false,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AppBar(
      iconTheme: const IconThemeData(color: Colors.black),
      title: Text(title, style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
      leading: showBackButton
          ? BackButton(
        onPressed: () {
          context.router.pop();
        },
      )
          : null,
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      elevation: 0.0,
    );
  }

  @override
  Size get preferredSize => const Size.fromHeight(56.0);
}
```

Comment: The error says "In this case, multiple heroes had the following tag: <default FloatingActionButton tag>" . You are using multiple `FloatingActionButton`, in which case each one needs a unique tag https://stackoverflow.com/a/66039316/20997501