# Flutter when i m trying to navigate to another page i got this error 'There are multiple heroes that share the same tag within a subtree'

Tags: flutter

Here is my code, how can i solve that?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aeUKn.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xL9ID.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZfr0.png)

Answer (score 0):

you are using Hero widget in your screens and have the same tag, search for Hero in your screen and give it different tag or remove it

Answer (score 0):

please refer to this example may be you have given one herotag to 2 different widgets.

[There are multiple heroes that share the same tag within a subtree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51125024/there-are-multiple-heroes-that-share-the-same-tag-within-a-subtree)

refer to above link for example