# There are multiple heroes that share the same tag within a subtree. While navigation by using Navigator pop

Tags: flutter, materialbutton

While navigating from one page to another after clicking material button, I'm getting the following error
`Within each subtree for which heroes are to be animated (i.e. a PageRoute subtree), each Hero must have a unique non-null tag. In this case, multiple heroes had the following tag: <SnackBar Hero tag - Text("Data Saved")> Here is the subtree for one of the offending heroes: Hero`
Here I'm using 3 material button, one is for save, cancel and delete.
I'm navigating in save button.

Comment: You should only used unique tag with navigator ```push``` and ```pop```. For ```pop``` you can pass arguments from previous screen widget constructor.

Comment: @LaPyae Please check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51125024/there-are-multiple-heroes-that-share-the-same-tag-within-a-subtree

Comment: You have to give different hive tag while navigation

Comment: above link is not helping

Comment: Link is working and I mean like that @rahulVFlutterAndroid. Thanks for ref.

Comment: @LaPyae Welcome, puted as answer

Comment: @Hinata are get your solution?

Comment: No Rahul, still getting the same error, can anyone share me your mail id or contact number so that I can explain what my problem is....

Comment: In the above link, the code is different and mine is different.

Comment: variyarahul6677@gmail.com

Comment: found the solution

Comment: please check your mail rahulVFlutterAndroid, I have sent you the code