# Unique Hero Tags are causing non-unique hero error (NO floating button) | Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a listbuilder that contains another listbuilder, to create a horizontal view inside a vertical one. These Cards contain a Column with A clipRRect and a ListTile, and are wrapped Heros with unique tags generated from their index.

However, when clicking on them, i still get `There are multiple heroes that share the same tag within a subtree.` errors, but when I print their index on press they are confirmed to be unique. **Oh, and they still open correctly with the right index?!**

Ever article ive found is only answered with `add heroTag to multiple instances of floatingButtons` with the only similar issue mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51125024/there-are-multiple-heroes-that-share-the-same-tag-within-a-subtree#comment98500887_51359266), however it doesnt have a solution, and isnt exactly the same issue.

Heres a code snippet of one of the cards, and the expanded view. (I understand this is pretty terrible flutter code, only been here for a couple days)

```dart
class _VenueCardState extends State<VenueCard>{


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return SizedBox(
      height: 240,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: InkWell(
          child: Hero(
            tag: 'v_venue_expanded_${widget.index}',
            child: Card(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  // TOP IMAGE OF THE CARD
                  ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                      topLeft: Radius.circular(6.0),
                      topRight: Radius.circular(6.0),
                    ),
                    child: Image.asset(
                      widget.imageurl,
                      fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                      height:150,
                      width: double.maxFinite,
                      ),
                    
                  ),
                  // LOWER TEXT AND ICON OF THE CARD
                  Row(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                    children: [
                      Expanded(
                        child: Column(
                          children:[
                            ListTile(
                              title: Text(
                                widget.name,
                                style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                              ),
                              subtitle: Text('${widget.local} | ${widget.contact} | ${widget.phone}'),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Column(
                        children : [
                          IconButton(
                            onPressed: () => _expandVCard(context),
                            icon: const Icon(IconData(0xe098, fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons')),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              )
            ),
          ),
          onTap: () => _expandVCard(context)
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _expandVCard(BuildContext context){
      print(widget.index);
      Navigator.of(context).push(
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => 
        
        Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(title: Text("${widget.name}'s Event")),
          body: Center(
            child: Hero(
              tag: 'v_venue_expand_${widget.index}',
              child: VenueCardExpanded(
                name: widget.name ,
                imageurl: widget.imageurl,
                local: widget.local,
                contact: widget.contact ,
                text: widget.text,
                phone: widget.phone,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        )
      )
    );
  }
}
class _VenueCardExpandedState extends State<VenueCardExpanded>{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
     return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey[860],
        body: SizedBox(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 106
        ,
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Card(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                // TOP IMAGE OF THE CARD
                ClipRRect(
                  borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(6.0),
                    topRight: Radius.circular(6.0),
                  ),
                  child: Image.asset(
                    widget.imageurl,
                    fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                    height:190,
                    width: double.maxFinite,
                    ),
                  
                ),
                // LOWER TEXT AND ICON OF THE CARD
                SizedBox(
                  height: 100,
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                    children: [
                      Expanded(
                        child: Column(
                          children:[
                            ListTile(
                              title: Text(
                                widget.name,
                                style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                              ),
                              subtitle: Text('${widget.local} | ${widget.contact} | ${widget.phone}'),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Column(
                        children : [
                          IconButton(
                            onPressed: (){
                              Navigator.of(context).pop();
                            },
                            icon: const Icon(IconData(0xe098, fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons')),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Flexible(child:
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          child: Text(widget.text != "" ? widget.text : "Veniam ea aliquip ipsum pariatur voluptate non ipsum elit sunt duis aute. Adipisicing proident et nostrud amet velit anim est occaecat exercitation in ea proident ullamco. Qui culpa voluptate deserunt nostrud non aliquip mollit ipsum dolor quis duis commodo labore. Ullamco sint adipisicing Lorem eu nulla labore magna occaecat ex irure mollit minim. Reprehenderit culpa minim elit in ullamco mollit consequat nulla. Ullamco consequat labore nostrud tempor tempor non enim.", ),
                        )
                      ),
                    ],                  
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                    children: [
                      const IconButton(onPressed: null, icon: Icon(Icons.favorite_outline)),
                      ElevatedButton.icon(onPressed: null, icon: const Icon(Icons.share), label: const Text("Share")),
                    ],
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          )
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

If you have any idea whats happening, i would be very appricative, thank you

as per request
the listbuilder code and its instanciation:

```dart
 HomePageBody(
        // ! THESE ARE CAUSING ERRORS (multiple heros with same tag) however work flawlessly and are unique. Cant find a post online or anything.
        vCards : List<VenueCard>.generate(20, (int index) =>  
          VenueCard( index: index+10, imageurl: "../images/nightsky.jpg",name: "name ${index + 10}", local: "local", contact: "contact", phone: "phone", text: ""),
        ),

        // This will eventually be replaced with a builder that reads from a database, for now they are just manual
        hCards: List<HorzScrollVenueCard>.generate(10, (index) =>
          HorzScrollVenueCard( index: index, imageurl: "../images/nightsky.jpg",name: "name $index", local: "local", contact: "contact", phone: "phone", text: ""),
        )

      ),
class _HomePageBodyState extends State<HomePageBody>{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    final _height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return SizedBox(
      height: _height,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
        child: ListView.builder(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          addAutomaticKeepAlives: false,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: widget.vCards.length + 1,
          itemBuilder:(context, index){
              if(index == 0){
                return SizedBox(
                  height: (_height / 100) * 37,
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      const Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
                        child: Text(
                          "Tonight",
                          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w600, fontSize: 20)
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height:(_height / 100) * 34 ,
                        child: ListView.builder(
                          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                          addAutomaticKeepAlives: false,
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          itemCount: widget.hCards.length,
                          prototypeItem: widget.hCards.first,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index){
                            return widget.hCards[index];
                          },
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              }else if(index == 1){
                return Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    const Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
                      child: SizedBox(
                        height: 27,
                        child: Text(
                          "Upcoming",
                          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w600, fontSize: 20)
                        )
                      ),
                    ),
                    widget.vCards[0]
                  ],
                );
              }else{
                return widget.vCards[index-1];
              }
              
          },
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: can you add the `ListBuilder` code, that's most likely the source of the problem